# load external lib dependency on the client side in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, requirejs, importerror

am a beginner in reactjs..

I have a question for all the experts who can help me in resolving the issue am facing.

My question- What are the different ways we can import external dependency file using reactjs other than 'import' keyword.

Thanks 
-Vijay

FYI.. this the follow up of the previous with little more understanding.

Hi.. thanks for the reply.. Yes I can give what is the issue am facing.

Am currently loading the dependency carousel file like the following

```
window.requirejs(['product-carousel/dist/product-carousel.bundle'], (carouselData) => {
        const carouselData = {};
        carouselData.CAROUSEL_STYLE_PAGES = carousel.CAROUSEL_STYLE_PAGES;
    });
```

am not getting this file loaded consistently., sometimes I get undefined error.

I initially tried using 'import' keyword but because of some compilation error I got to move to this method

Please help me how to get this loaded without fail.
-Vijay

Comment: Hello, can you please clarify why you want this and whats the use of it? This may make it quite easier to help you, and if you tag `importerror` we might be able to resolve this error for you

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the reply.. Yes I can give what is the issue am facing.

Am currently loading the dependency carousel file like the following

 window.requirejs(['product-carousel/dist/product-carousel.bundle'], (carouselData) => {
   const carouselData = {};
   carouselData.CAROUSEL_STYLE_PAGES = carousel.CAROUSEL_STYLE_PAGES;
  });

am not getting this file loaded consistently., sometimes I get undefined error.

I initially tried using 'import' keyword but because of some compilation error I got to move to this method

Please help me how to get this loaded without fail.
-Vijay

Comment: And what is the error with that? It looks like a normal import

Comment: Updated in the main desc..

Comment: I see the issue like "vent" of undefined., When this file is not loaded...